# I can't understand fully this line of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, readability, lis

I was solving a problem on **LIS** **(Longest Increasing Subset)** and I couldn't solve it completely. I googled for some solutions and on rosettacode I found several ones. I liked this one because it looks very short and straight forward (so easier to understand). But it's written in such a way that I am having serious troubles rewriting it.

```
for i in range(len(d)):
        l.append(max([l[j] for j in range(i)
                     if l[j][-1] < d[i]] 
                         or [[]], key=len) 
                   + [d[i]]
                )
```

This is the part I am having troubles to understand. This is what I think I understood:

*append to the solutions array the longest combination of numbers in the solutions array, lower than the current number i am considering from the input array; plus the number you are considering from the input array.* (Sorry for my English).

I feel like I didn't understand fully what the code is doing.

```
def longest_increasing_subsequence(d):
    'Return one of the L.I.S. of list d'
    l = []
    for i in range(len(d)):
        l.append(max([l[j] for j in range(i) if l[j][-1] < d[i]] or [[]], key=len) 
                  + [d[i]])
    return max(l, key=len)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for d in [[3,2,6,4,5,1], [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15]]:
        print('a L.I.S. of %s is %s' % (d, longest_increasing_subsequence(d)))
```

Comment: short code isn't necessarily more readable! I'd suggest expanding out the list comprehension into a separate nested `for` loop and seeing if that helps

Comment: I reformatted the line just a bit to make it easier to read.  By all means, re-code this as an explicit `for` loop and explicit call instead of `key=len`.

Comment: thank you, I am going to study and try to understand it now

Comment: "Readability counts." https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me expand out the code for you:

```
def longest_increasing_subsequence(d):
    'Return one of the L.I.S. of list d'
    l = []
    for i in range(len(d)):
        # currently the LIS is just this number
        lis_at_this_index = [d[i]]
        # for all the previous LIS
        for j in range(i):
            # if d[i] can be added to it and still be increasing
            if l[j][-1] < d[i]:

                # update the candidate LIS at this index
                lis_at_this_index = max(lis_at_this_index, l[j] + [d[i]], key=len)
        l.append(lis_at_this_index)
    # return the global maximum
    return max(l, key=len)
```

The idea is that if we have the LIS for indices [0..i-1], we can compute the LIS for index `i` like so:

1. For each LIS [0...i-1], check if adding d[i] is allowed
2. If it is allowed that is a candidate LIS for index i
3. The longest out of all the candidates is the LIS at index i

And then you return the longest out of all the LIS at each index.